# why i can't replace the "for Each" with "for" loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

hey everyone(; i'm using "js" to create tabs in my html .
 i guess i'm missing something, but i do not understand why i can't replace the **forEach** loop with **for** loop.
 this is my js:

```
var divsList = [];
var div = document.createElement("div");

function asTabs(container) {
    for (var i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = container.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            divsList.push(child);
        }
    }
    console.log(divsList);

    divsList.forEach(function (tab, i) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = divsList[i].getAttribute("data-tabname");
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            select(i);
        });
        div.appendChild(button);
    });
    container.insertBefore(div, container.firstChild);
}
/*for (var i = 0; i < divsList.length; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = divsList[i].getAttribute("data-tabname");
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            select(i);
        });
        div.appendChild(button);
    }
    container.insertBefore(div, container.firstChild);
    console.log(container);
}*/

function select(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divsList.length; i++) {
        divsList[i].id = "Tab";
        if (n === i) {
            divsList[i].style.display = "";
            div.childNodes[i].style.background = "#FBFBFB";
        } else {
            divsList[i].style.display = "none";
            div.childNodes[i].style.background = "";
        }
    }
}
asTabs(document.querySelector("#wrapper"));
select(0);
```

and this is my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div data-tabname="one"><span>ONE</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in porta augue. Proin iaculis turpis eget orci commodo, id aliquam nisi eleifend. Nulla nec gravida nibh, sed dapibus lorem. Cras non tempus erat, sed </div>
        <div data-tabname="two"><span>TWO</span> Quisque pellentesque lacus sollicitudin arcu hendrerit euismod. Proin sed quam rutrum, dapibus dolor sed, blandit lorem. Quisque sed libero et eros vehicula lobortis. Mauris eleifend scelerisque mollis. Quisque mollis nibh dui, quis blandit ligul</div>
        <div data-tabname="three"><span>THREE</span> Sed lorem mi, pellentesque eget porta at, viverra at ex. Quisque viverra eu lorem a tempor. Donec ultrices ullamcorper elementum. Vivamus ut varius mauris. Suspendisse nisi 
        </div>
    </div>
```

the **forEach** work great. but as you can see I comment out the **for** loop  because it's not work.The buttons are created nicely but the **select** function that executed by the **EventListener** does not work well with the **for** loop.
[here is the link to codepen:](https://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/oeXoEM)

Comment: Exactly how is it not working? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Yes, of course you can substitute a "for()" loop.  No, "for (...) {}` (the "for" keyword, loop syntax, and a code block)  is *NOT* equivalent to "forEach(<<function>>)".  Look up [closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).  Specifically: "A closure is a function having access to the parent scope, even after the parent function has closed."

Comment: You need to use `for` with `let` to create the same scope for `i` as the `forEach` does